# How to generate Dapp Url? which can be used in status app browser to run our dapp in mobile?

Tags: status-im

I want to develop an mobile app using ethereum, for that I'm using status app as a wallet in mobile. But i'm stuck at the point that actually what is the Dapp URL which we have to add in Status browser? How to generate Dapp Url? Can anyone explain me the whole process. Please help me out with this

Comment: Provide code, screenshots, definitions, a more specific question, as is, seems like you are asking how to use a particular app

Answer (score 0):

1. Get an ENS node, can be `yourname.stateofus.eth` that you can obtain in names.statusnet.eth for 10 SNT, or create an auction in https://registrar.ens.domains/ , or even use some free/paid here https://now.ens.domains/. You can also buy names on marketplaces like Name Bazaar.
2. Publish your dapp on IPFS
3. Go to `manager.ens.domains` and set Resolver content to your IPFS hash (in hex).

A more detailed guide: https://gist.github.com/PhyrexTsai/cffcbfa1d752b9cf817d920dfcd1ec9f